# OSS Server Written in Javascript, Linux Based Needs MIME Configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, linux-networking, httpd, node.js, mime

Scenario:

There is a popular OSS application named Potree, hosted in GitHub. I am getting minimum support from its author, a very talented but busy guy who does not know much Linux or Apache. This is the great app that I desire to conquer and give her a home:

[WebGL point cloud viewer for large datasets](https://github.com/potree/potree) - [Scroll down, you can actually run it]

I have been able to find and fix several obstacles (thanks again, guys!) but one last detail remains.

The request arrives to Apache as follows:

http://jfknumbers-forum.org/potree-1234

Notice the Proxy Host configuration below. It works like a charm.

[Section of httpd.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPRNb.jpg)

Such request is dutifully forwarded to the target server, which is listening in port localhost:1234.

You can see the problem immediately. Instead of displaying what is expected, all we see is a listing of the directory where the server was started.

[Directory Listing Only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gA0w.jpg)

That was a puzzle that lasted weeks, but now I am informed about the nature of the problem: The MIME types have to be properly configured.

I got stuck there, and I rather ask the real experts. This is a job for Stack Overflow (or subsidiaries thereof).

The implementation seen below is running at the University of Arkansas, the only problem being that it is deployed on a Windows server:

[Petroglyph Point Lavabeds National Monument](http://view3d.cast.uark.edu/petroglyphpoint)

so the owner could only help me so much. He told me about the MIME requirement.

TIA!

Comment: Does the service at `http://localhost:1234/` work correctly in itself?

Comment: Yes, perfectly. I have been testing it for a couple weeks. Lots of people have downloaded that service and it works, on Linux, Windows and Macs unmodified.

As long as it is on localhost, that is.